# continuous data interpreted as categorical - best modeling strategy

Tags: regression, classification

I'm working on a project with data that has a continuous endpoint, but the interpretation of the endpoint is categorical.  For example, my endpoint ranges from 1 to 100, with "above 50" and "below 50" considered normal and abnormal.

For modeling, I've proposed to model the endpoint as continuous using standard regression techniques, and the prediction can be interpreted as categorical as described.  Alternatively, I could do classification modeling by creating a binary variable based on the endpoint, but that seems inconsistent with the nature of the data to me.  However, classification accuracy is the desired performance metric.

Is there a preferred method to operate in this circumstance?

Comment: If your performance metric doesn't care how much below or above 50, go with binary classification. If it might be interesting how much (or how surely), perform a regression but use a matching loss function / performance measure (eg RMSE)

Comment: It sounds like survival analysis might be relevant for your problem.

Comment: Alert - is there any concern about loss of information if we convert to binary?  It would seem we have more information on the continuous variable that we're ignoring work a binary variable.

Comment: Stephen Kolassa - unfortunately we don't have time to event information.  Only a continuous value that is interpreted categorically.

Comment: Alert above should be AlexR.  Oops.